# Java application does not works as jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a java application that fills a jasper Report and generates a PDF file, when i run my application in netbeans everything works good.
But if i pack my application to a unique Jar file (including all the libraries) and use it to create an exe file (with launch4j), that is runned by another program the result is a PDF file where the accented letters doesn't appear.

I've tryed to run the application from cmd "java -jar application.jar" but the result is the same, so i think the error is in the packaging.

This is the code that i've added to my build.xml file to create the Jar:

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

        <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
             minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
             <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
        -->
        <property name="store.jar.name" value="PdfEngine"/>


        <!-- don't edit below this line -->

        <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
            excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        </zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

    </target>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try running the application this way - `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar application.jar`

Comment: Solved thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752323/java-native-language-application-doesnt-work-outside-ide

Comment: Am just curious, could you try my solution on an older build that may exist with you?